# How to speed up compilation with fancyqr?

Tags: qrcode

I use `fancyqr` to generate qrcode on large LaTeX documents (more than 500 pages). There is a lot of qrcode to generate which increases the compilation time. How to reduce the time of creation of qrcode? (or avoid regenerating them at each compilation).

Comment: Put them in their own file using `standalone`, compile those, and input just the resulting pdfs with `graphicx`.

Comment: Thanks you !  
For information : my child file
` 
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fancyqr}
\fancyqrset{height=2.5cm,level=H,padding}
\begin{document}
\fancyqr{mylink}
\end{document}
`